# Passing multidimensional array in another way?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
#include <stdio.h>

void arraypass(int from, int to, int a[][2]);

int main()
{
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    int t1 = 0, t2 = 0;
    int testArray[10][2];

    for (t1 = 0; t1 < 10; t1++)
    {
        testArray[t1][t2] = t1 + 1;
    }

    t2++;

    for (t1 = 0; t1 < 10; t1++)
    {
        testArray[t1][t2] = t1 + 10;
    }

    arraypass(1,5,testArray);

    return 0;
}

void arraypass(int from, int to, int a[][2])
{
    int b;
    for (b = from; b <= to; b++)
    {
        printf("%d ",a[b][0]);
        printf("%d\n",a[b][1]);
    }
}
```

Why is it that

```
int a[][2]
```

works, but not

```
int a[][]
```

for the argument definitions in this?

```
void arraypass(int from, int to, int a[][2]);
```

And, is there a way to possibly pass an entire multidimensional array at once, or do I need to perform some kind of loop?

Comment: You may learn how a multidimensional **array** is stored in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the compiler, a vector is a hidden pointer to its first item.
For example:

```
int a[2];
a[0]=0;
a[1]=1;
```

is the same of:

```
int a[2];
*(a+0)=0;
*(a+1)=1;
```

When you pass a multidimensional array (o a simple array) you should use pointers instead of a vector:

```
void arraypass(int from, int to, int **a);
```

and then if you want to use it you could do something like this:

```
void arraypass(int from, int to, int **a){
int i,j;
for(i=from; i<end; i++) {
for(j=0; j<2; j++) {
printf("%d",a[i][j]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that arrays decays to pointers. That means, when they are (for example) passed as arguments to functions the function receives a pointer.

What `int a[][2]` does, is the same as `int (*a)[2]`, which means that `a` is a pointer to an array of two `int`. That is different from a pointer to an array of any other dimension, which is why you don't have to specify the primary "dimension" (as that to the compiler is the same as a pointer) but you do have to specify the other "dimension(s)".

Comment: Okay, but how would I send another segment of the array properly then?

Answer (score 0):

This is related to [this answer](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html) in the C FAQ.

Because the function receives a pointer when an array is passed to a function, the compiler needs to know the dimensionality of the array that the pointer will be to (in this case, two), but doesn't care how long the sequence of pointers to two-element arrays is going to be.